# Collisions and Lists

Tags: xna, c#, collision-resolution

I've run into an issue that breaks my collisions. Here's my method:

- Gather Input
- Project Rectangle
- Check for intersection and ispassable
- Update

The update method is built on `object_position * seconds_passed * velocity * speed`. Input changes velocity and is normalized if > 1.

This method works well with just one object comparison, however I pass a list or a for loop to the collision detector and velocity gets changed back to a non zero when the list hits an object that passes the test and the object can pass through.

Any solutions would be much appreciated. Side note is there a more proper way to simulate movement?

Comment: Please try to provide at least some code and use more punctuation to logically group your statements. I've tried to fix formatting, but I'm not really sure it's what you've had in mind.

Comment: [This suggested edit](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29626) would add code and make various improvements, but the edits fundamentally change the question and come from a different user...

Answer (score 1):

Lets see what you're trying to do : you're trying to check if 1 entity collides with N other entities, but I suppose those collide as well. Basically (if I understood you right) you`re trying to do N*N comparisons every frame, or even N. You should, first and foremost, switch your data structure. Use a quadtree, with that, you will have a complexity of O(n*n(logn)), which is close to linear speed.

Also, the velocity negating itself - this is just a response to the collision, for instance in pong-like games its a common practice to negate one part of the velocity vector.

This is just general advice based on what you said, please provide code and I`ll be more specific.